# security constraints with JAAS

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, annotations, authorization, jaas

i decided to write my own JAAS login module. So far everything works fine, yet there is something i can't google out. Assume the login function by *LoginContext* has successfuly authenticated a user. How do I attach user roles to the authenticated subject so that it works with security constraints in web.xml file? Also how do I make it work with security annotations for my session beans? The way of aquiring the user roles is clear of course, the question is where do i put this data so it throws an exception on privileged functions if not authorized. I am using glassfish 3 and the point of my attempt is to create something like databaseloginmodule from jboss. Thank you for reading this, any hints, keywords are welcomed. stu

Comment: See if this can help you in your quest:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971590/jboss-login-and-redirect-to-correct-url

Answer (score 0):

If you're using glassfish3, did you already consider the jdbc realm?

http://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/mort_learns_jdbc_realm_authentication

Comment: Yea I did, but the point is for me to understand how does the authentication in jaas work. Thx anyway, I should have rather framed my question like "how does JAAS authenticate the session".