# Jboss login and redirect to correct url

Tags: java, jsf, authentication, jboss, profiling

I  have this problem and i just cannot find a solution to it.

I am using JBoss AS 7 and created a dynamic web project using Eclipse Indigo.  From my project i created a simple login form whereby after correctly logging in i should be directed to my appropriate section.

Users, Roles and Groups should be managed by jboss and not the project.  So jboss should decide where to redirect me after checking in the correct properties files.

How can i do this? Can you all help me please.

Comment: no one knows about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i finally got it. Three simple steps to follow.

1. In the web.xml file, put all your security constraints according to the roles.

   Authentication
     
      any name
      *.jsf
      GET
      POST
     
     
      admin
     
     
      NONE
2. The login config

   FORM
     realm name
     
      /mylogin.jsf
      /myerror.jsf
3. security role

   desc
        admin

Create a jboss-web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder.  Inside this file, write

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/realmname</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Create a folder classes in the WEB-INF folder and place your user.properties and role.properties file in it.

And then the final step is to add the configuration in the standalone.xml file

```
<security-domain name="realmname">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```